# Embedding a UIContainerView as a portion of screen in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview, embedding, collectionview

I have a screen in my storyboard where I would like to embed a container view into a portion of the screen. I can't figure out if I should add a new containerview or view from the object library and then drag in a collection view controller or collection view (or tackle it a different way?). I've tried all combinations but just end up with the embedded view being shown black even if I drag collection view cells and set a background colour to test it. Once I can get this working I plan to populate the cells from an external database.

Any suggestions please? I'm doing this using storyboard as far as possible.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you drag a container view into your view, you automatically get an embedded view controller, whose size is matched to the container view's size. You should delete that controller, and drag in a UICollectionViewController. Control drag from the container view to this controller and choose embed when you let go -- this will resize the collection view controller. You can give the collection view a background color, so you will see where it is, but giving the cells a background color won't show up until you implement the methods in the controller to populate those cells.

Comment: That's great,thanks.. So I've added a container view then a collection view to the new screen. I've still got the problem that its blank even after changing the colour of the cell, should I expect it to show straight away upon running (to know it's working)?

Comment: @Peej, actually, I think I told you wrong. You probably want to use a collection view controller. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Brilliant @rdelmarv.. Thanks for your help, something new seeing the embed option on control-drag.

Comment: For anyone needing to build on this I found an excellent tutorial http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_6_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial